# How can I play a sound on all devices when an element is added to a scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to notify all users of a web app that a new element has been added to a $scope by playing a beep. So when a new element turns up in an ng-repeat the app goes beep.
I can do that easily enough on the screen where the element is being added (as shown below) but can't find out how to play a beep for everyone.

```
$scope.beep = function(){
    beep.play();
};

$scope.addMeal = function(meal) {
    if(meal.food != null && meal.calories != null){
            $scope.todaymeals.$add(meal);               
            if(angular.isDefined($scope.meal)){
                delete $scope.meal;
                beep.play();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would need to use websockets through server to have all users connected

Comment: I'm using firebase is there a way to use its 3 way binding to do it

Comment: This example from Firebase might help: [Three-Way Data Binding with Firebase and Angular](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-04-firebase-angular-data-binding.html) "When data changes in one client, those updates are immediately persisted to Firebase and rendered across all clients"

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just easily call the onchildadded method:

```
ref.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
  beep.play(); //In Your case
});
```